# Default value of a variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am writing a simple function, that makes my menu dynamic, loading pages on button click. HTML looks like that:

```
<button id="appnav" value="button1" type="button" onclick="app(this.value)">Button 1</button>   
<button id="appnav" value="button2" type="button" onclick="app(this.value)">Button 2</button>
<button id="appnav" value="button3" type="button" onclick="app(this.value)">Button 3</button>


<div id="app-div">

</div>
```

And JavaScript file looks like this:

```
function app(clickVal) {
var clickVal;

  if (clickVal == "button1") {
  document.getElementById("app-div").innerHTML = "PAGE 1";
  } 

  else if (clickVal == "button2") {   
 document.getElementById("app-div").innerHTML = "PAGE 2";
  }

  else if (clickVal == "button3") {
 document.getElementById("app-div").innerHTML = "PAGE 3";
  }

}
```

And this part works well, but the window (div id="app-div") is empty until one of the buttons is clicked. I would like to assign a default value to it. I've tried to do that by writing this function

```
    function defaultValue () {
      document.getElementById('app-div').innerHTML = "PAGE 1";
    }
```

and trying to launch it onload of app-div, but it still didn't work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Just put the starting HTML in the div... `<div id="app-div">PAGE 1</div>`

Comment: on dom ready, call your function

Comment: If you can't add it to the HTML for some reason, just add `app("button1")` after the function, and make sure the whole thing is in a script element after the div in question. (Also, unrelated to what you're asking, remove `var clickVal;` from the beginning of the function, it doesn't make sense to redeclare the function argument.)

Comment: You cannot have **duplicate ID**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks correct. In the defaultValue function check that "document.getElementById('app-div')" is not null or undefined. Also just to throw this out there, you set innerHTML to a string "PAGE 1". I assume you know this is not really HTML syntax. Maybe you should set the value to actual HTML tagged content with the text "PAGE 1" as the content of a div for example.

Comment: Yes, I eventually plan on adding React DOM elements, so the values are actual HTML. Thank you.

Comment: Why would setting `.innerHTML` to `"PAGE 1"` be a problem? That's valid content for a div element, there's no need to include extra tags.

Comment: It's not a problem, rather an observation/question.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the default value function when your DOM is ready for modifications:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', defaultValue, false);
```

The snippets below could be added for compatibility purposes:

```
window.addEventListener('load', defaultValue, false );

document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", defaultValue);

window.attachEvent("onload", defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could obviate the `default` Value function and call your function

```
function app(clickVal) { ... }

app("button1");
```

even if it is a default value should be specified directly in html

```
<div id="app-div"> PAGE 1</div>
```

Comment: I've specified default in HTML and that works, I guess it doesn't benefit me at all to do it in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have

```
<div id="app-div">
    PAGE 1
</div>
```

On clicking the button, the innerHtml of `#app-div` will be replaced. No need for `defaultValue()`